# Postgres EXPLAIN BUFFERS total buffers counts for query

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan, explain

I'd like to know the total count of buffers hit, read etc. for the query.

I thought that would be the numbers shown by the topmost "Buffers:" line in the EXPLAIN output, because the documentation states "The number of blocks shown for an upper-level node includes those used by all its child nodes."

However, sometimes that number is smaller than the numbers of the child nodes (for instance, the shared hits count for the topmost node (a GATHER) is 11k and the shared hits for its only child node (a NESTED LOOP) is 30k). The rule about children buffers statistics seems to hold for the NESTED LOOP node, though.

What am I missing?

`SELECT version()` says
`PostgreSQL 10.1 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9), 64-bit`, this is a RDS database instance.

Comment: EXPLAIN ANALYZE output for parallel queries are a bit of a mess, in my experience.  It is hard to know what is being reported in total, and what is reported for just the leader.  I usually turn off parallelization when I want an easier to understand EXPLAIN.

Comment: "SELECT version() says PostgreSQL 10.1" The current version is 10.12. you are missing well over 1000 commits to the code.  I don't know if any of those are relevant, but I also don't know that they are not.

Comment: @jjanes, thanks for the parallel queries suggestion, that's my conclusion too, that things are messed up at the GATHER level. As for the Postgres version, that's not really something I can control, I really hope it will get updated at some point :-)